# Android - Php Echo string not working

Tags: php, android

I am loading some Information from a Database, and then echoing it so I can read it on my Android Device. It has been working well so far, but for some reason one specific entry in the database is not loading correctly. I am echoing the data as follows:

```
echo ($row['POST_NAME'] . " ^ " . $row['POST_URL'] . " GOT HERE");
```

For all entries the information is being echoed correctly. However for one post, it returns the following:

```
Test Post ^ glamourmenot.weebly.com
```

As you can see, the "GOT HERE" is missing. Because of this, I tried to echo the URL by itself. That worked fine. But as soon as I attempt to add something afterwards it fails. What could be causing this issue?

The data type on the Database is set to:

```
Text: utf8_general_ci
```

EDIT:
Here is how I am reading the data on the Android Application:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
String line = "";
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
    break;
}
in.close();
String responseString = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Any chance that `$row['POST_URL']` has a trailing newline sequence? You don't say how you are reading the returned data, but if it's by reading one line, then that would explain the missing `" GOT HERE"`.

Comment: Weird. I take it you're logging `responseString` or looking at it in a debugger? You might try using `trim($row['POST_URL'])` in your `echo` command, but from the code you posted it looks like my guess isn't really the problem.

Comment: trim would remove the white space correct? I can try it.

Comment: No luck. Still the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I have resolved the issue. As Ted Hopp Suggested, it was an Issue with a new line sequence. I resolved it by doing this:

```
echo echo str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), "", textToEcho);
```

This removes all of the new line characters.

Comment: Glad you resolved it. You should mark your answer as the solution. `trim()` only removes leading and trailing white space; it won't remove new line sequences embedded in the text. I take it that was the problem?

Comment: Yes the New Line sequence was the issue. If you like you can submit your answer and Ill mark that one as the solution. :) Thanks again

Comment: Your answer is the solution; there's no need for me to post another. Also, I still don't understand why your Android code didn't read all the lines or why eliminating the newlines fixed the problem.

Comment: @TedHopp I agree, append() should've handled the newLine properly, and toString() would've reversed that and showed it as a proper string.